# Azure OMSforLinux functionality

Tags: azure, redhat, azure-monitoring, azure-linux

H All

I'm trying to get a full list of functionality the OMS agent for Linux provides in Azure. I understand it provides host level and guest level monitoring, but what other benefits are there for it? Also would anyone know if it makes any changes to the OS, apart from configuring the agent to gather the data\metrics.

Also are there any known issues with RedHat VMs?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/log-analytics-agent#other-services),

> The agent for Linux and Windows isn't only for connecting to Azure
>   Monitor, it also supports Azure Automation to host the Hybrid Runbook
>   worker role and other services such as [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/change-tracking), [Update
>   Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-update-management), and [Azure Security Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-intro). For more information about the
>   Hybrid Runbook Worker role, see [Azure Automation Hybrid Runbook
>   Worker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker).

Also, you can see the [supported scenarios](https://github.com/microsoft/OMS-Agent-for-Linux#supported-scenarios) for more details.

note that, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/log-analytics-agent#agent-prerequisites

> Either rsyslog or syslog-ng are required to collect syslog messages.
>   The default syslog daemon on **version 5 of Red Hat Enterprise** Linux,
>   CentOS, and Oracle Linux version (sysklog) is not supported for syslog
>   event collection. To collect syslog data from this version of these
>   distributions, the rsyslog daemon should be installed and configured
>   to replace sysklog.